# Saving users and items features to HDFS in Spark Collaborative filtering RDD

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I want to extract users and items features (latent factors) from the result of collaborative filtering using ALS in Spark. The code I have so far:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating

// Load and parse the data
val data = sc.textFile("myhdfs/inputdirectory/als.data")
val ratings = data.map(_.split(',') match { case Array(user, item, rate) =>
  Rating(user.toInt, item.toInt, rate.toDouble)
})

// Build the recommendation model using ALS
val rank = 10
val numIterations = 10
val model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations, 0.01)

// extract users latent factors
val users = model.userFeatures

// extract items latent factors
val items = model.productFeatures

// save to HDFS
users.saveAsTextFile("myhdfs/outputdirectory/users") // does not work as expected
items.saveAsTextFile("myhdfs/outputdirectory/items") // does not work as expected
```

However, what gets written to HDFS is not what I expect. I expected each line to have a tuple (userId, Array_of_doubles). Instead I see the following:

```
[myname@host dir]$ hadoop fs -cat myhdfs/outputdirectory/users/*
(1,[D@3c3137b5)
(3,[D@505d9755)
(4,[D@241a409a)
(2,[D@c8c56dd)
.
.
```

It is dumping the hash value of the array instead of the entire array. I did the following to `print` the desired values:

```
for (user <- users) {
  val (userId, lf) = user
  val str = "user:" + userId + "\t" + lf.mkString(" ")
  println(str)
}
```

This does print what I want but I can't then write to HDFS (this prints on the console).

What should I do to get the complete array written to HDFS properly?

Spark version is 1.2.1.

Comment: try saving users.mapValues(_.mkString(" ")) instead of users. in that way, the features will be saved as string instead of hash values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JohnTitusJungao is right and also the following lines works as expected :

```
users.saveAsTextFile("myhdfs/outputdirectory/users") 
items.saveAsTextFile("myhdfs/outputdirectory/items")
```

And this is the reason, `userFeatures` returns an `RDD[(Int,Array[Double])]`. The array values are denoted by the symbols you see in the output e.g. `[D@3c3137b5` , `D` for double, followed by `@` and hex code which is created using the Java toString method for this type of objects. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/3415409).

```
val users: RDD[(Int, Array[Double])] = model.userFeatures
```

To solve that you'll need to make the array as a string :

```
val users: RDD[(Int, String)] = model.userFeatures.mapValues(_.mkString(","))
```

The same goes for items.